# Neck Started paining after abs workout

Tags: abdominals

I am new to abs exercises. I am doing this exercise [8-Min Abs Workout](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vkKCVCZe474)
for past two days.

While doing exercise i am feeling lot of stress in my neck and abdomen. Today i am getting neck pain (front side) while gently pressing along sides of the food pipe.
 Am i doing anything wrong ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

My first impression of viewing that video was how could you not get a sore neck from that movement?  The movement shown appeared to put a lot of stress on the neck and trap muscles.  Maybe you should try supporting your neck with your hands.

Answer (score 2):

That is because you aren't really doing proper crunches.

Your problem is you are raising your head through your hands.

So, your head is being lifted up via your hand. This is not how you should do it.

Rather, keep your head stable, and let your abs squeeze and do the work.

Here, is how you do it.

[How to do proper crunches](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MKmrqcoCZ-M)

See how the tension is constantly on abs and head is always stable.

Answer (score 0):

Many of the exercises in that video are also available on Insanity or P90X and they are done in ways that don't put pressure on the neck. 
 
 
Modify your exercises or search for those videos and see how they are done.